# FindBugs shows only first error in method (Jenkins, IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: intellij-idea, jenkins, findbugs

I'm using Jenkins with FindBugs plugin installed for static code analysis. Also, every developer on the team have FindBugs IntelliJ IDEA plugin installed to do the same.

The problem is that in Jenkins, only first occurence of an error in a method is reported. In Idea, all problems are reported as single errors. For example:

```
public String myMethod() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(String.format("First \n"));
    sb.append(String.format("Second \n"));
    sb.append(String.format("Third \n"));
    sb.append(String.format("Fourth \n"));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

in this method, Idea reports 4 errors of type VA_FORMAT_STRING_USES_NEWLINE. On jenkins server, there is actually only one error, on line with string `First \n`.

Is there a way to configure either Jenkins or Idea to behave uniformly?

Versions:

- IntelliJ Idea Enterprise 12.1.3
- FindBugs-IDEA plugin 0.9.97
- Jenkins 1.513
- Jenkins findbugs plugin 2.0.2

Comment: You may have jenkins setup to fail the build and stop processing as soon as it finds an error -- which is fairly normal. Idea however continually reassesses every line of code through its static analyser, meaning that it won't stop when it finds an error. I wouldn't think that you'd want to change the behavior of either.

Comment: @EngineerDollery hi, actually I'd like to change the behavior so that both tools gives exactly the same results. However, I don't know how to change the behavior of either

Comment: First you need to make sure where the problem lies. Did you double check the input for the plugin is correct, as in does the xml file have 4 entries of the error? And have you tried using the plugin from the jenkins repositories instead of the idea version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found so far is to use a different plugin, eg. [QAPlug Findbugs](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4597?pr=). This one reports results exactly the same as Jenkins does.

The downside is it is a bit more clumsy than FindBugs-IDEA plugin.